# How to make GNU Parallel takes input from multiple files with record separator

Tags: linux, multithreading, unix, parallel-processing, gnu

I have a code that can be executed the following way:

```
$ ./mycode [param1] [param2] [input1-fasta] [input2-fasta] [output-file]
```

To execute it for example:

```
 $ ./mycode 4 4 input.fasta input2.fasta output.txt
```

Typically the code would do all-against-all sequence comparison.

Fasta files look like this:

```
>Seq_1 
TTTGTTTGCTTCATATTGTAATTAATTTTAAAGAAA
>Seq_2
CTGTGACAAATTGCCCTTAACCCTGTGACAAATTGC
```

Note that the number of sequences of both input may be different.

What I want to do is to run that code command with multiple core and chunking the files automatically using [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).
Hoping that it would run faster.

So I tried this command:

```
$ parallel --pipe --recstart '>' "./mycode 4 4 input.fasta input2.fasta output.txt"
```

But it fail to execute and it give me this instead:

```
parallel: Warning: Input is read from the terminal. Only experts do this on purpose. Press CTRL-D to exit.
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It is not really clear what you expected this would do:

```
parallel --pipe --recstart '>' "./mycode 4 4 input.fasta input2.fasta output.txt"
```

If you want all-against-all I would suggest you split big file into chunks and then test each chunk against the small file. So something like:

```
cat big.fasta | parallel --pipe --recstart '>' "./mycode 4 4 small.fasta - output{#}.txt"
```

To use --pipe your program must be able to read from standard input (stdin), thus the '-'. If it cannot try bash's redirection magic:

```
cat big.fasta | parallel --pipe --recstart '>' "./mycode 4 4 small.fasta <(cat -) output{#}.txt"
```