# How to make gnu-parallel split multiple input files

Tags: linux, gnu-parallel

I have a script which takes three arguments and is run like this:

`myscript.sh input1.fa input2.fa out.txt`

The script reads one line each from `input1.fa` and `input2.fa`, does some comparison, and writes the result to `out.txt`. The two inputs are required to have the same number of lines, and `out.txt` will also have the same number of lines after the script finishes.

**Is it possible to parallelize this using GNU `parallel`?**

I do not care that the output has a different order from the inputs, but I do need to compare the `i`th line of `input1.fa` with the `i`th line of `input2.fa`. Also, it is acceptable if I get multiple output files (like `output{#}`) instead of one -- I'll just `cat` them together.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397929/how-to-make-gnu-parallel-takes-input-from-multiple-files-with-record-separator) topic, but the answer wasn't quite what I wanted.
I know I can `split` the two input files and process them in parallel in pairs using `xargs`, but would like to do this in one line if possible...

Answer (score 0):

If you can change myscript.sh, so it reads from a pipe and writes to a pipe you can do:

```
paste input1.fa input2.fa | parallel --pipe myscript.sh > out.txt
```

So in myscript you will need to read from STDIN and split on TAB to get the input from input1 and input2.

Comment: Clever! This will be faster if it takes more time for `myscript.sh` to process and output to STDOUT than `paste` to go through the entire file, correct? Worded differently, if `myscript.sh` is as fast as `paste`, then there are no performance gains, correct?

Comment: paste is fairly quick, so the limiting factor may be parallel.