# GNU parallel: parallel files by id

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I would like to parallelize a script. I know a bite gnu-parallel, but maybe it is not really appropriate for my problem. 
I have several GFF input files (column are separated by tabulations) and I would like to parallelize them for my script. All of files contain the same ids.

> File 1 :
>   id1 ...
>   id2 ...
>   id2 ...
>   id3 ...
>
> File 2 :
>   id2 ...
>   id3 ...
>   id3 ...

The two files are different : the number of line is not the same, ids are identical but not necessary present everywhere ( I find this answer [How to make gnu-parallel split multiple input files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622295/how-to-make-gnu-parallel-split-multiple-input-files), but the number of lines is the same in all input files) . I do not  want to concatenate them because I want to keep the information from which data set they come from. And I do not want to change the GFF format. 
For the moment, I am splitting my files by id and running my script. I need to keep all of id1 together (id2 together, etc) , but my script can take several id at the same time. And I do not need to run the combination File1 id1 - File2 id2, just File1 id1, File1 id2 - File2 id2 etc. As sometimes one id has not a lot of data it can be run with other ids (run1 : File1 id1, File1 id2 - File2 id2 ; run2 : File1 id3 - File2 id3, etc) . So is it possible to split efficiently my input data, by making some groups depending of the id and the amount of data for each ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it is really hard to understand what you are trying to do. If I got it wrong, please show us examples of what you expect to be run.

I assume your program reads from stdin and that you want the IDs grouped, so you get all the id1s in a single run and do not chop a group into multiple calls.

My suggestion is to merge File1 and File2, insert a marker before each ID group, let GNU Parallel read a block using the marker as record separator, remove the record separators and pass that to `yourprog`:

If File1+File2 are sorted:

```
sort -m File1.gff File2.gff |
```

If not:

```
sort File1.gff File2.gff |
```

Insert marker:

```
perl -pe '/^([^\t]+)/; if($1 ne $l) { print "Ma\rke\r"; } $l=$1;' |
```

Look for Ma\rke\r, split into 10MB blocks, remove markers, pass to yourprog:

```
parallel --pipe --recstart 'Ma\rke\r' --rrs --block 10M yourprog
```

Edit (20220918):

Today you would use `--group-by`.

Comment: I think it is not possible to parallel multiple files (create block for file1 and for file2 idependently ?), isn't it ? So the easiest way could be to first split my files (file1.a , file1.b file2.a file2.b...) and to parallel my program with 
parallel  "myProg --input1 {1} --input2 {2} " ::: file1.*.gff ::: file2.*.gff

Comment: Sounds right. parallel --xapply myProg --input1 {1} --input2 {2} ::: file1.*.gff ::: file2.*.gff  We assume that file1.1.gff has the ids relevant for file2.1.gff

Answer (score 1):

Since 20190222 you can use `--shard`:

```
cat *gff | parallel --shard 1 -j8 yourprog
```

This will look at column 1, compute a hash, and send it to an instance of `yourprog` depending on the hash value modulo 8.